# Pasar un valor de una tab a otra

Tags: android, google-maps

Tengo dos tabs en una aplicación Android. Una de ellas me carga un listado y la otra me posiciona los ítems de este listado. Desde la tab2 quiero acceder al listado de la tab1. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Definición de tabs:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(getString    
(R.string.label_listado)),ListFragment.class, null);

 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(getString  
 (R.string.label_geoposionar),getResources().getDrawable  
 (android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map)),MapsFragment.class, null);
```

Probé a hacer lo siguiente:

```
MapsFragment ClaseMapa=new  MapsFragment();
ClaseMapa.newInstance(listado);
```

Sin embargo no me funciona, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear la variable de tipo lista en la actividad donde ejecutas la transacción de los fragments y puedes acceder al valor de esa lista desde el fragment

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).lista;
```